# htaccess 404 redirect works for .html extension but not .php extension

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, file-extension

I have made a custom 404 page and inserted in my htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

And the error direct works properly whenever I test a url with no extension or an .html extension. However, when I type in a url with a .php extension, a blank page with the message "No input file specified." pops up.

What do I have to do to make my custom 404 page pop up for .php file extensions as well?

Comment: maybe you have a another `htaccess` that is sensitive with `.php`

Comment: Are there `RewriteRule`s in your .htaccess file? If so, what are they?

Comment: I see this error with codeignighter, are you using codeignighter? I believe they use a bootstrap to route files within the framework.

Comment: no, i'm not using codeigniter, just a normal custom cms website with minor dynamic functions in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when PHP is compiled as a `CGI Binary` in your server. In such cases even if you have `apache` 404 defined, the request for PHP gets passed over to the `CGI binary` which gives this error when the file to process is not found (`No input file specified`).

The solution to this problem will vary based on various other config params, but essentially what you should try to do is first check the URL, and if it does not exist, translate it into a non-php url so that the rule kicks in and shows the correct 404.

Not tested but something in the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^.+\.php$ /non_existant_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the directory

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yoursite.com/404.php
```

If your local then like this

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 directory/404.php
```

Comment: I'm assuming the directory is set, `/404.php` would mean `{document root}/404.php`